# How to import an existing SQLite table into Android Room?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm developing a trivia app and I have finished implementing Room Persistence into the app, but I'm having trouble finding info where I can import an existing table from a SQLite db file that I'm shipping with the app.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "import a db file into the app"?

Comment: Asset file----?

Comment: I meant importing the data into the Room tables.

Comment: Every piece of documentation on Room shows it being used to create a database. But let's say we have an existing SQLite database at `custom/path/database.db`. How can we map the in-memory classes to that location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a little bit late but i solved this issue by this solution.
you need to copy your existing sqlite db file to `/data/data/{your package name}/databases` directory before you initialize room databse

you can use this method to copy file

```
   public static void copyDataBase(Context context, String dbName) throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(dbName); 
    String outFileName =  "/data/data/"
            +context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/databases/" + dbName;
    File file=new File(outFileName);
    if (file.exists())
        return; 
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

    } 
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

and then in your application class do this:

```
public class ErrorReporterInit extends Application  {

public static ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

@Inject
DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector; 

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    try {
        GeneralUtil.copyDataBase(this,"{your existing db file in asset}");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .application(this).build();
    applicationComponent.inject(this);

}



@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
}

}
```

in my case i initialize room as a dependency using dagger