# Room unexpected behavior when working with BLOB & TEXT

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, android-room, robolectric

I am migrating my app's **SQLite** helper to **Room**. Basically what I am doing is just copying data from old **SQLite** database to **Room**, so due to schema mismatch I need to provide migration. I am having this issue with BLOB data in **Room**. 
I have below simple model

```
class NewCourse {
    var weekday: Array<String> = arrayOf()
}
```

I also have `TypeConverter` as

```
@TypeConverter
fun toArray(concatenatedStrings: String?): Array<String>? {
    return concatenatedStrings?.split(",".toRegex())?.dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }?.toTypedArray()
}

@TypeConverter
fun fromArray(strings: Array<String>?): String? {
    return strings?.joinToString(",")
}
```

Within my old `appdatabase.db` database I have a corresponding table `Course` with a field `weekday` which has a type `BLOB`.

Well, because of my `TypeConverter` in room database I will have `weekday` with a type `TEXT`. While migrating I running below `SQL` script.

```
INSERT INTO NewCourse (weekday) SELECT weekday FROM Course
```

As `weekday` from `Course` table is `BLOB` type and in `SQL` you can basically store anything to anything, am I expecting it will copy `BLOB`-typed `weekday` in `Course` to `TEXT`-typed `weekday` in `NewCourse`.
Well at first I was expecting some error due to type mismatch. But "fortunately", but not expectedly, **Room** doesn't throw any exception and it gets value of `BLOB` and copies as `TEXT`.

My first question was why it is working? i.e. how it's copying the `TEXT` value of `BLOB` to my newly created table?

I never cared about it, as it was working perfectly, until I did some testing with **Robolectic**. 
Unfortunately, I am getting error if I start testing with **Robolectic**. After copying data in my migration, when I query for `NewCourse` I am getting SQL error of

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Getting string when column is blob. Row 0, col 10
```

So, I suppose here it is copying the data as `BLOB` and when querying for `weekday` it is throwing an exception as `getWeekDay` calls `getString` of cursor.

My second question would be "Why while testing with Robolectic it is not working as it is working with just running the app?"

I also tested the queries with just Sql not involving Android, and over there it copies the `BLOB` as `BLOB` even though the type of `weekday` at `NewCourse` is `TEXT` as expected.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290948/how-to-import-an-existing-sqlite-table-into-android-room

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, but how does room storing it as `TEXT`? Because if you do the same insert operation in `sqlite3` for example it stores as `BLOB`. Assuming Room does conversion, then why I it is not doing the same for Robolectric case?

Answer (score 1):

**Robolectric** is a testing library for android applications. The keyword here is testing and by that it means there shouldn't be any exception. **Robolectric** showing you error maybe because of some android devices may throw exception so your application will crash. Try checking your logs while your application running. Maybe you are missing some warnings.